# How Can I Change Datepicker language ( NG-ZORRO ) - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ng-zorro-antd

the first component contains a form in French,
and the second component contains an English form,
So the question how can I change or switch the language of datepicker
the technologies used are Angular and NZ-ZORRO
thanks in advance ...

Comment: this may help you https://ng.ant.design/docs/i18n/en

Answer (score 0):

you use this in your app.module.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import en from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import fr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(en);
registerLocaleData(fr);
```

Then you use [nzLocale] in your different templates to bind it to the desired language.

Source:
https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en#api